# Templated += operator overloading with std::pair assignment

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to build a signal/slot in C++ 11, I wanted to have the "connect" function being used through the += operator, but since the += operator can only take a single argument, and in order to take a member function which is callable, I also need the object pointer as well.

Therefore, I have to make the argument a std pair
The code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>

class listener{
public:
    void on_event(){ /* ... */ }
};


class event{
public:
    template<typename T, typename F = void(T::*)()>
    void operator+=( std::pair<T*, F> p ){
        /* ... */
    }
};


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    event e;
    listener l;
    e += std::pair(&l, &listener::on_event); // works
    e += std::make_pair(&l, &listener::on_event); // works
    e += {&l, &listener::on_event}; // NOT works!!
}
```

My question is, how can I make it works with just {} on the user side?
Many thanks!

Comment: That doesn't work because it's an initializer list, you probably need to overload it for that.

Comment: Does it fails at compile or run time? What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add a specific function overload that isn't templated:

```
void operator+=(std::pair<listener*, void(listener::*)()> p) {
    // Delegate to the other one (But prevent infinite
    // recursion by specifying it's the template one)
    operator+=<listener>(p);
}


e += {&l, &listener::on_event};
```

But this would only work for `listener` objects. I would suggest making a member function that takes 2 arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void add(T& object, F&& method) {
    operator+=(std::pair<T*, F>(std::addressof(object), std::forward<F>(method)));
}

e.add(l, &listener::on_event);
```